# Identity related to Ramanujan's congruences

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

A very simple question: how do you prove the following identity:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty p_{5k+4}x^k=5\frac{\phi(x^5)^5}{\phi(x)^6},$$
where
$$\phi(x)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty 1-x^n,$$
and $p_n$ is the partition function?
The wikipedia article on Ramanujan's congruences mentions this identity, and says that this identity is how Ramanujan proved the congruence $p_{5k+4}\equiv 0$ (mod 5). The article also gives a link, but this link only proves the congruence, not the identity.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_congruences

https://zenodo.org/records/1447425

Edit: The strategy of the commenter below works. The equation can be expressed in terms of the Dedekind eta function as follows (if I didn't make a mistake):
$$\frac{1}{5}\sum_{\ell=0}^4\frac{e^{2\pi i\frac{5\ell}{24}}}{\eta(\frac{\tau+\ell}{5})}=5\frac{(\eta(5\tau))^5}{\eta(\tau)^6}.$$
One could check that both sides of the equation transform in the same way under the maps
$$\tau\longmapsto\frac{a\tau+b}{c\tau+d},$$
for $\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}$ in the group
$$\Big\{\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{Z}^{2\times2}\Big|ad-bc=1\text{, and }5|c\Big\},$$
which I believe to be generated by
$$\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}\quad\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\quad\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
5 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\quad\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1\\
5 & -2
\end{bmatrix}\quad\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & -1\\
5 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
,$$
so it is enough to check it for these matrices. I don't see how these modular forms of weight -1/2 can be interpreted as sections of line bundles, but raising both sides to the power 4, or even to the power 24, realises them as sections of line bundles on modular curves, and it is enough to check equality for these 24th powers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x=\exp\{2\pi i z\}$, both sides of the equality are suitable modular forms for suitable subgroups of $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$. So by the Riemann-Roch theorem, there exist a explicitly computable $M$ (and relatively small), such that if the $k$-th coefficients of the Fourier expansion of both sides are equal for all $k<M$, then the two sides must be equal, because of the finite dimension of the modular subgroups.